# Get random string that is not in list

Tags: python, random

I have a list of choices. Let's assume it's `['active', 'inactive', 'deleted']`. I want to get a random string that isn't in that list (for example, `disabled`) and complication is that I don't want to look into that list myself (function must work universally for any list of string).

I know how to get random string from list with `random.choice`. What I want is to have inversed equivalent of it.

Actual case - I want to write a unittest with an `assertNotIn` assertion.

So, my code at the moment is below:

```py
import random
import string

insiders = ['active', 'inactive', 'deleted']

while True:
    outsider = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(random.choice(range(1, 10))))
    if outsider not in insiders:
        break
```

My question is: Is there any shorter solution? Ideally, one-liner. Something like this:

```py
outsider = random.not_in_list(insiders)
```

Comment: How would `not_in_list` know you want a string of between 1 and 9 ASCII letters?

Comment: @ScottHunter length doesn't matter. The question is purely theoretical. I want to know is there any other ways to solve this task.

Comment: The point is that `not_in_list` needs to know what universe you want strings chosen from, and has no means to do so.

Comment: `'x'.join(insiders)` produces a string that's guaranteed not to be in your list.  Not very random, though.

Comment: @jasonharper publish this as an answer, that's a good solution of which I haven't even thought of.

Comment: @ScottHunter your words means only that `not_in_list` needs some extra params. I don't mind. I just mean It doesn't matter how you answer this question. You clawed into a hypotetical solution which I'm looking for, it makes no sense, really!

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in a question I have a solution at the moment. It's based on a `random.choice` method and generates string with arbitrary length (from 1 to 9 symbols):

```py
import random
import string

insiders = ['active', 'inactive', 'deleted']

while True:
    outsider = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(random.choice(range(1, 10))))
    if outsider not in insiders:
        break
```

Result:

```py
'aJirzLZjD'
# or
'x'
# or
'PYxAeL'
# and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

Poster requested onliner that's equivalent to the posted code.

Option using:

- Python 3.8+ using Walrus Operator and generator

**Code**

```
import string
from random import randint, choice

outsider = next(outsider :=''.join(choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(randint(1, 10))) for _ in range(1000000) if outsider not in insiders))
```

**Explanation**

Use for loop with large number (1000000) rather than while True

The generator will output the next occurrence that satisfies the conditional

```
generator =  (outsider :=''.join(choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(randint(1, 10))) for _ in range(1000000) if outsider not in insiders)
```

Outsider is obtained from the generator

```
outsider = next(generator)
```

**Test**

```
for k in range(10):
  print(next(generator))
```

*Output*

```
Pbt
zrGtZVvDsT
yMYND
up
xkA
mBzApOP
AoV
VJLd
cIGPkBWI
Tp
```